# Breakup a rather large android project into smaller components

Tags: android, file, project, structure

I'm still quite new to developing android programs and getting in to trouble with my current project. It started of as a simple small project but it is getting way to big for one file.

I would like to split it up in several components for example ui, calculations and main. But what is the best way to do this.

Currently I've only got :

```
public class main extends Activity {...}
```

and

```
public class preference extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {...}
```

Should I remove the functions from main an put it in for example:

```
public class ui extends main {...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is up to you to organize your project accordingly. My way of doing things is to have the following packages:

- **activities**: Where I place all the activties.
- **types**: Where I place all the types, like: `User` or `Country`.
- **exceptions**: Where I place all my custom exceptions.
- **services**.
- **providers**: for the content providers.
- **preferences**.
- **util**: a package that holds all the classes that might be useful as a tool (like JSON parsers, String utility classes, Regular expressions etc.).

etc.

Inside the `activities` package you could add one class by activity. Calling one class `ui` is not a good idea, `ui`could be the name of the package (insead of activities). You should call your class in a way that it describes the functionality of your activity. For instance you can call it: `LoginScreenActivity`. I encourage you to check some open source projects like [Shelves](http://code.google.com/p/shelves/) or [Foursquare](http://code.google.com/p/foursquared/) to study a possible way of organizing your android projects.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I understand that I should be careful with the names of my classes. But for example I've got only one activity and want to split it up. Can I just create several classes and use the functions of these classes in all files if I make them public?

Comment: Actually it really depends on the code that you are writing. You have to create a new class each time it makes sense to you. If it makes sense yes you can create several classes and import them in your main activity. But, if the methods that you want to move elsewhere belong to this class then you should not in my opinion split them up. The idea is that the code organisation should be driven by design and logic not by kloc (or number of lines of codes):)

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna dive into the projects you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I would follow a MVC/MVP/MVVM approach. I'm currently in a big Android project too, and I'm trying to divide my files by a model/view/ namespaces.